# Change Layouts from Navigation Drawer (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, navigation-drawer

I know this is a basic question but none of the tutorials I found could fully explain this to me.

So I have the MainPage.xaml which has the Navigation Drawer.

[image]

Then I have a TransferPage.xaml which has different content on it. I tried doing this:

```
private void MyListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    if (StartListBoxItem.IsSelected)
    {
        frame.Navigate(typeof(TransferPage), null);
    }
}
```

But that didn't work. I need to transfer from page one to page two while **keeping the navigation drawer.**

Please ask me to be more specific before downvoting.

Comment: Use a reference to the existing frame rather than creating a new one every time you handle the selection change. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/navigationview for more info, there is an example halfway down that shows the 'ContentFrame' xaml definition and c# code to show how to navigate...What you are doing is creating a Frame that is not on the page and asking it to navigate. It may be doing what you ask but it is not on the page and so is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CodexNZ said the `frame` that instantiated is not on the page. For you requirement, you could set the `frame` for `SplitView.Content` like the following:

```
<SplitView.Content>
    <Frame Name="MyFrame"/>
</SplitView.Content>
```

And navigate to another page with it, For more detail you could refer to this [code sample](https://github.com/Windows-Readiness/AbsoluteBeginnersWin10/tree/master/UWP-024/UWP-024).

```
private void MyListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MainItem.IsSelected)
    {
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
    }
    else if (FavouritItem.IsEnabled)
    {
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(FavouritePage));
    }
}
```